# materialize css: remove gap/space between grid

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

Is there any idea how to remove gap/space between the grid?
Here's an example of code for each columns, it will show the gap/space between grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card-panel light-blue">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card-panel light-blue">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card-panel light-blue">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you see the styles you will be able to see the padding between each col, can't you remove that if you want to?

Comment: So you suggest to edit the materialize.css? it's crap dude

Comment: you don't need to edit materialize css, you can override the styles if you really want to do that. but why you want to remove that padding anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `padding: 0;` to `.row .col.s4` in your main css file.

```css
.row .col.s4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card-panel light-blue">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card-panel light-blue">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s4">
    <div class="card-panel light-blue">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```